# There is no row at position 0 error

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, position, row

I have the following code:

```
Do Until i = dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows.Count
                strRepID = dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows(i)("repID").ToString
                strLBP = dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows(i)("officename").ToString
                strLBPEmail = dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows(i)("cemail").ToString
                strCCRepEmail = dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows(i)("cc1").ToString
                strRepName = dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows(i)("firstname").ToString & " " & dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows(i)("lastname").ToString
                strRepEmail = dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows(i)("email").ToString
                strRepPhone = dsSalesRep.Tables(0).Rows(i)("phone").ToString

                searchStr3 = "SELECT * FROM LookupSalesRep WHERE repID='" & strRepID & "'"
                Dim SqlAdapter3 As New SqlDataAdapter(searchStr3, myConn2)
                Dim dsTerritories As New DataSet
                myConn2.Open()
                SqlAdapter3.Fill(dsTerritories)
                strCountry = dsTerritories.Tables(0).Rows(0)("country").ToString
                'strCountry = dsTerritories.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString
```

When I run the web page, though, it gives me the error:  There is no row at position 0.

But when I use the code

```
strCountry = dsTerritories.Tables(0).Rows.Count.ToString
```

strCountry gets the right number of rows. Please help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in a loop and at some point the table (dsTerritories.Tables(0)) is null. Check first if the table is null:

```
If dsTerritories.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    strCountry = dsTerritories.Tables(0).Rows(0)("country").ToString
End If
```